# A conjecture regarding odd perfect numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, conjectures, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

(Note:  This question has now been cross-posted to [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/q/310919).)

Let $\sigma(z)$ denote the sum of the divisors of $z \in \mathbb{N}$, the set of positive integers.  Denote the [deficiency](http://oeis.org/A033879) of $z$ by $D(z):=2z-\sigma(z)$, and the [sum of the aliquot divisors](https://oeis.org/A001065) of $z$ by $s(z):=\sigma(z)-z$.

If $n$ is odd and $\sigma(n)=2n$, then $n$ is said to be an [odd perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers).  Euler proved that an odd perfect number, if one exists, must have the form $n = p^k m^2$, where $p$ is the special / Euler prime satisfying $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(p,m)=1$.

Starting from the fundamental equality
$$\frac{\sigma(m^2)}{p^k} = \frac{2m^2}{\sigma(p^k)}$$
one can derive
$$\frac{\sigma(m^2)}{p^k} = \frac{2m^2}{\sigma(p^k)} = \gcd(m^2, \sigma(m^2))$$
so that we ultimately have
$$\frac{D(m^2)}{s(p^k)} = \frac{2m^2 - \sigma(m^2)}{\sigma(p^k) - p^k} = \gcd(m^2, \sigma(m^2))$$
and
$$\frac{s(m^2)}{D(p^k)/2} = \frac{\sigma(m^2) - m^2}{p^k - \frac{\sigma(p^k)}{2}} = \gcd(m^2, \sigma(m^2)),$$
whereby we obtain
$$\frac{D(p^k)D(m^2)}{s(p^k)s(m^2)} = 2.$$
Note that we also have (**Equation A**)
$$\frac{2D(m^2)s(m^2)}{D(p^k)s(p^k)} = \bigg(\gcd(m^2, \sigma(m^2))\bigg)^2.$$ 
Lastly, notice that we can easily get
$$\sigma(p^k) \equiv k + 1 \equiv 2 \pmod 4$$
so that it remains to consider the possible equivalence classes for $\sigma(m^2)$ modulo $4$.  Since $\sigma(m^2)$ is odd, we only need to consider two.

Here is my question:

> Which equivalence class of $\sigma(m^2)$ modulo $4$ makes **Equation A** untenable?

Comment: Note that $\sigma(m^2)/p^k = \frac{m^2}{\sigma(p^k)/2}$ is a **square** if and only if $\sigma(p^k)/2$ is also a square.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Further to [this recent corrigendum in NNTDM](https://nntdm.net/volume-29-2023/number-1/181-184-corrigendum/), which corrects an oversight in [Some modular considerations regarding odd perfect numbers – Part II](https://nntdm.net/volume-26-2020/number-3/8-24/), we realized that we do in fact have the following biconditionals:

> In this article, we consider the various possibilities for $p$ and $k$ modulo $16$, and show conditions under which the respective congruence classes for $\sigma(m^2)$ (modulo $8$) are attained, if $p^k m^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $p$. We can prove that:
>
> - $\sigma(m^2) \equiv 1 \pmod 8$ holds if and only if $p + k \equiv 2 \pmod {16}$
> - $\sigma(m^2) \equiv 3 \pmod 8$ holds if and only if $p - k \equiv {12} \pmod {16}$
> - $\sigma(m^2) \equiv 5 \pmod 8$ holds if and only if $p + k \equiv {10} \pmod {16}$
> - $\sigma(m^2) \equiv 7 \pmod 8$ holds if and only if $p - k \equiv 4 \pmod {16}$.

---

If $k=1$, then these logical equivalences take the form

> - $\sigma(m^2) \equiv 1 \pmod 8$ holds if and only if $p \equiv 1 \pmod {16}$
> - $\sigma(m^2) \equiv 3 \pmod 8$ holds if and only if $p \equiv 13 \pmod {16}$
> - $\sigma(m^2) \equiv 5 \pmod 8$ holds if and only if $p \equiv 9 \pmod {16}$
> - $\sigma(m^2) \equiv 7 \pmod 8$ holds if and only if $p \equiv 5 \pmod {16}$.

Answer (score 3):

(The following answer is copied verbatim from the corresponding [MO link](https://mathoverflow.net/a/340106/10365).)

The following assertion appears in Theorem 3.3 (page 7, equations (5) to (6)) of [Odd multiperfect numbers by Shi-Chao Chen and Hao Luo](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1102.4396.pdf):

> Let $n=\pi^{\alpha} M^2$ be an odd $2$-perfect number, with $\pi$ prime, $\gcd(\pi,M)=1$, and $\pi \equiv \alpha \equiv \pmod 4$.  Then
> $$\sigma(M^2) \equiv 1 \pmod 4 \iff \pi \equiv \alpha \pmod 8,$$
> $$\sigma(M^2) \equiv 3 \pmod 4 \iff \pi \equiv \alpha + 4 \pmod 8.$$

Answer (score 2):

I cannot answer your question, but I proved two claims which might be useful to answer your question.

This answer proves the following claims :

**Claim 1** : In $\text{mod}\ 4$, $$\sigma(m^2)\equiv 1\iff \frac{m^2}{\gcd(m^2, \sigma(m^2))}\equiv \frac{\sigma(m^2)}{\gcd(m^2, \sigma(m^2))}\iff \text{$\dfrac{2p^k-\sigma(p^k)}{4}\ $ is even}$$

**Claim 2** : $$\sigma(m^2)\equiv \frac{(t+1)t}{8}\bigg(4+(t^2+1)(v-1)\bigg)\pmod 8$$
where $p\equiv t\pmod{16}$ and $k\equiv v\pmod{16}$.

(Though Claim 2 is "weaker" than what you've already known, it may be useful since all the cases are included in one expression.)

---

**Claim 1** : In $\text{mod}\ 4$, $$\sigma(m^2)\equiv 1\iff \frac{m^2}{\gcd(m^2, \sigma(m^2))}\equiv \frac{\sigma(m^2)}{\gcd(m^2, \sigma(m^2))}\iff \text{$\dfrac{2p^k-\sigma(p^k)}{4}\ $ is even}$$

*Proof* :

In this proof, we consider in $\text{mod}\ 4$.

Let $$G= \gcd(m^2, \sigma(m^2)),\quad m^2=Ga,\quad\sigma(m^2)=Gb$$
where $a,b$ are odd such that $\gcd(a,b)=1$.

Then, we see that the **equation A** is equivalent to
$$2D(m^2)s(m^2) = G^2D(p^k)s(p^k)$$
i.e.
$$2(2Ga-Gb)(Gb-Ga)=G^2\bigg(2p^k-\sigma(p^k)\bigg)\bigg(\sigma(p^k)-p^k\bigg)$$
i.e.
$$2(2a-b)(b-a)=\bigg(\underbrace{2p^k-\sigma(p^k)}_{\equiv\ 0}\bigg)\bigg(\underbrace{\sigma(p^k)-p^k}_{\equiv\ 1}\bigg)$$
i.e
$$(2a-b)(b-a)=2c(4d+1)\tag1$$
where $c,d$ are integers such that
$$2p^k-\sigma(p^k)=4c,\qquad \sigma(p^k)-p^k=4d+1$$

So, we have, from $(1)$,
$$3ab-2a^2-b^2\equiv 2c\tag2$$
Since $a^2\equiv b^2\equiv 1$, we finally have, from $(2)$,
$$ab\equiv 2c+1\tag3$$

Now, from $(3)$, we get the followings :

- If $G\equiv a\equiv 1$ and $b\equiv 1$, then $\sigma(m^2)\equiv 1$, and $c$ is even.
- If $G\equiv a\equiv 1$ and $b\equiv 3$, then $\sigma(m^2)\equiv 3$, and $c$ is odd.
- If $G\equiv a\equiv 3$ and $b\equiv 1$, then $\sigma(m^2)\equiv 3$, and $c$ is odd.
- If $G\equiv a\equiv 3$ and $b\equiv 3$, then $\sigma(m^2)\equiv 1$, and $c$ is even.

Therefore, we can say that

$$\sigma(m^2)\equiv 1\iff a\equiv b\iff \text{$c$ is even.}\quad\blacksquare$$

---

**Claim 2** : $$\sigma(m^2)\equiv \frac{(t+1)t}{8}\bigg(4+(t^2+1)(v-1)\bigg)\pmod 8$$
where $p\equiv t\pmod{16}$ and $k\equiv v\pmod{16}$.

*Proof* :

We have

$$\sigma(m^2)\equiv p^km^2\bigg(\frac{\sigma(p^k)}{2}\bigg)^{-1}\equiv p^k\bigg(\frac{\sigma(p^k)}{2}\bigg)^{-1}\equiv p^k\bigg(\frac{\sigma(p^k)}{2}\bigg)\pmod 8$$

Let $p=16s+t\ (t>1), k=16u+v$ where $t^4\equiv 1\pmod{16}$.

Then, there is an integer $z$ such that
$$\begin{align}\frac{\sigma(p^k)}{2}&\equiv \frac 12(1+t+\cdots +t^k)\pmod{8}
\\\\&\equiv \frac{t^{k+1}-1}{2(t-1)}\pmod{8}
\\\\&\equiv \frac{1}{2(t-1)}\bigg(-1+t^2(t^4)^{\frac{k-1}{4}}\bigg)\pmod{8}
\\\\&\equiv \frac{1}{2(t-1)}\bigg(-1+t^2(t^4-1+1)^{\frac{k-1}{4}}\bigg)\pmod{8}
\\\\&\equiv \frac{1}{2(t-1)}\bigg(-1+t^2\sum_{j=0}^{\frac{k-1}{4}}\binom{\frac{k-1}{4}}{j}(t^4-1)^j\bigg)\pmod{8}
\\\\&\equiv \frac{1}{2(t-1)}\bigg(-1+t^2\bigg(1+\frac{k-1}{4}(t^4-1)+(t^4-1)^2z\bigg)\bigg)\pmod{8}
\\\\&\equiv \frac{1}{2(t-1)}\bigg(-1+t^2+\frac{k-1}{4}(t^4-1)t^2\bigg)\pmod{8}
\\\\&\equiv \frac{t+1}{2}+\frac{k-1}{2}t^2\frac{(t^2+1)(t+1)}{4}\pmod{8}
\\\\&\equiv \frac{t+1}{2}+\frac{v-1}{2}t^2\frac{(t^2+1)(t+1)}{4}\pmod{8}\end{align}$$

Also, since $t^2\equiv 1\pmod 8$,
$$p^k\equiv (16s+t)^{16u+v}\equiv t^v(t^4)^{4u}\equiv t^v\equiv t\pmod 8$$

Therefore, we finally get
$$\sigma(m^2)\equiv \frac{(t+1)t}{8}\bigg(4+(t^2+1)(v-1)\bigg)\pmod 8$$
This holds even for $t=1$. $\ \blacksquare$

**Examples** :

If $p\equiv k\equiv 1\pmod{16}$, then $\sigma(m^2)\equiv 1\pmod 8$.

If $p\equiv 5,k\equiv 13\pmod{16}$, then $\sigma(m^2)\equiv 1\pmod 8$.

If $p\equiv k\equiv 9\pmod{16}$, then $\sigma(m^2)\equiv 1\pmod 8$.

If $p\equiv 13,k\equiv 5\pmod{16}$, then $\sigma(m^2)\equiv 1\pmod 8$.

Therefore, we can say that if $p+k\equiv 2\pmod{16}$, then $\sigma(m^2)\equiv 1\pmod 8$. (This is what you've already written in your answer.)