# A possible disproof for the Descartes-Frenicle-Sorli Conjecture on odd perfect numbers

Tags: proof-verification, conjectures, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

Let $\sigma(z)$ denote the sum of the divisors of $z \in \mathbb{N}$, the set of positive integers.  Denote the [deficiency](http://oeis.org/A033879) of $z$ by $D(z):=2z-\sigma(z)$, and the [sum of the aliquot divisors](https://oeis.org/A001065) by $s(z):=\sigma(z)-z$.  Finally, let the *abundancy index* of $z$ be denoted by $I(z):=\sigma(z)/z$.

If $n$ is odd and $\sigma(n)=2n$, then $n$ is said to be an [odd perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers).  Euler proved that an odd perfect number, if one exists, must have the form $n=p^k m^2$, where $p$ is the special / Euler prime satisfying $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(p,m)=1$.

Starting from the fundamental equality
$$\frac{\sigma(m^2)}{p^k}=\frac{2m^2}{\sigma(p^k)}$$
one can derive
$$\frac{\sigma(m^2)}{p^k}=\frac{2m^2}{\sigma(p^k)}=\gcd(m^2,\sigma(m^2))$$
so that we ultimately have
$$\frac{D(m^2)}{s(p^k)}=\frac{2m^2 - \sigma(m^2)}{\sigma(p^k) - p^k}=\gcd(m^2,\sigma(m^2))$$

The following is copied verbatim from this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3394489/28816) to a closely related question:

> It turns out that it *is possible* to express $\gcd(m^2, \sigma(m^2))$ as an integral linear combination of $m^2$ and $\sigma(m^2)$, in terms of $p$ alone.
>
> To begin with, write
>   $$\gcd(m^2,\sigma(m^2))=\frac{\sigma(m^2)}{p^k}=\frac{D(m^2)}{\sigma(p^{k-1})}=\frac{(2m^2 - \sigma(m^2))(p-1)}{p^k - 1}.$$
>
> Now, using the identity
>   $$\frac{A}{B}=\frac{C}{D}=\frac{A-C}{B-D},$$
>   where $B \neq 0$, $D \neq 0$, and $B \neq D$, we obtain
>   $$\gcd(m^2,\sigma(m^2))=\frac{\sigma(m^2)-(2m^2 - \sigma(m^2))(p-1)}{p^k - (p^k - 1)},$$
>   from which we get
>   $$\gcd(m^2,\sigma(m^2))=\sigma(m^2)-(2m^2 - \sigma(m^2))(p-1)=2m^2 - p(2m^2 - \sigma(m^2)) = 2m^2 - pD(m^2),$$
>   or equivalently,
>   $$\gcd(m^2,\sigma(m^2))=2(1 - p)m^2  + p\sigma(m^2).$$

Here is my **Question #1**:

> **Is it possible to obtain the following equation?**
>   $$2m^2 - \sigma(m^2)=\gcd(m^2,\sigma(m^2))=2(1 - p)m^2  + p\sigma(m^2)$$

**MY ATTEMPT**

Suppose that $2m^2 - \sigma(m^2)=\gcd(m^2,\sigma(m^2))$.  Then it follows that $m^2$ is [deficient-perfect](http://oeis.org/A271816), which then [implies](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.01868) that the Descartes-Frenicle-Sorli Conjecture that $k=1$ holds.  But notice that the variable $k$ is not present in the last equation above, so that it is not really relevant to consider the value of $k$ here.

By assumption, we have
$$2m^2 - \sigma(m^2)=\gcd(m^2,\sigma(m^2))=2(1 - p)m^2  + p\sigma(m^2),$$
from which it follows (**?**) that
$$\bigg(2(1-p)=2\bigg) \land \bigg(-1 = p\bigg),$$
which results (**?**) in the contradiction
$$\bigg(0 = p\bigg) \land \bigg(-1 = p\bigg).$$
Note that **either conjunct is already a contradiction**, as $p$ being the special / Euler prime it ought to satisfy $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

We therefore conclude that $m^2$ is not deficient-perfect.  This is [equivalent](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.01868) to $k \neq 1$.

Here is my **Question #2**:

> **Is this proof correct?  Is it even logically sound?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to resolve the *apparent* contradiction:

By assumption, we have
$$2m^2 - \sigma(m^2) = 2(1 - p)m^2 + p\sigma(m^2) = 2m^2 - pD(m^2).$$

Cancelling $2m^2$ from both sides of the **LHS** and **RHS** of the last equation, we get
$$\frac{\sigma(m^2)}{p}=D(m^2)=2m^2 - \sigma(m^2)$$
from which it follows that
$$I(m^2)=\frac{\sigma(m^2)}{m^2}=\frac{2p}{p+1}.$$
The last equation then implies that $k=1$, which is expected from the equation
$$2m^2 - \sigma(m^2) = \gcd(m^2,\sigma(m^2)).$$